# appcompat Toolbar and `animateLayoutChages=true`

Tags: android, android-appcompat

I added `animateLayoutChages=true` to the toolbar which makes UI nicer. But I discovered issue:
[image: child view]
[image: parent view]
[image: after opening menu]
Problem: padding for title is not set back after returning back from child view

Comment: so what is the problem here ??

Comment: Text timeline is shifted to right. Empty space where was HomeUp button before

Comment: Created ticket on android bug tracker https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=80955&thanks=80955&ts=1417003705 But would be workaround to trigger layout update